# Sending post request from a servlet

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, accesscontrolexception

I have been trying to send a POST request from a servlet and the code that I wrote is this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url.build());
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue));
post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse res = client.execute(post);
```

The URL is "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" and I send some parameters with this request.

However, when I run this I get `AccessControlException`.

The `HttpPost` method that I use here comes from `org.apache.http` i.e., commons HttpClient API. I have tried a lot but it doesn't seem to work.

So the question is "Is it possible to send a cross domain request using HttpClient?"

Comment: I don't know if it's still relevant, but I more or less copy-pasted this code and it worked. Could you please elaborate?
What parameters are you sending?